# Postgresql: An alternative to subqueries to make the query more efficient?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

So I have the following table with the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE stages (
  id  serial PRIMARY KEY,
  cid VARCHAR(6)  NOT NULL,
  stage varchar(30)  NOT null,
  status varchar(30) not null,
);
```

with the following test data:

```
INSERT INTO stages (id, cid, stage, status) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'first stage', 'accepted'),
  ('2', '1', 'second stage', 'current'),
  ('3', '2', 'first stage', 'accepted'),
  ('4', '3', 'first stage', 'accepted'),
  ('5', '3', 'second stage', 'accepted'),
  ('6', '3', 'third stage', 'current')
  ;
```

Now the use case is that we want to query this table for each stage for example we will query this table for the  **'first stage'** and then try to fetch all those **cids** which do not exist in the subsequent stage for example the **'second stage'**:

Result Set:

```
cid | status
2   | 'accepted'
```

While running the query for the **'second stage'**, we will try to fetch all those **cids** that do not exist in the **'third stage'** and so on.

Result Set:

```
cid | status
1   | 'current'
```

Currently, we do this by making an exists subquery in the where clause which is not very performant.

The question is that is there a better alternative approach to the one we're currently using or do we need to focus on optimizing this current approach only? Also, what further optimizations can we do to make the exists subquery more performant?

Thanks!

Comment: `Currently, we do this by making an exists subquery in the where clause which is not very performant.` Fix your table definition; add the natural key (maybe just as an index) Maybe also get rid of these silly fixed-size strings used as keyfields.

Comment: oh yes, all of that is already optimized. The stages are basically foreign keys with proper indexes in place. The above example is a dummied down version as its easier to understand.

Comment: If there isn't even a query in your question, and the DDL does not reflect your actual model, how could we possibly optimize that secret query?

Comment: oh okay now i get your point. Apologies. The purpose to provide such a DDL was not to hide the actual model but to hide away the complexities in order to make the example easier to understand. Thats all. But now I realize that all those foreign keys will actually play a part of the optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             lead(stage) over (partition by cid order by id) as next_stage
      from stages s
     ) s
where stage = 'first stage' and next_stage is null;
```

Comment: nice! I did not know about the lead method! Thanks! This will work I believe!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE stages (
  id  serial PRIMARY KEY
  , cid VARCHAR(6)  NOT NULL
  , stage varchar(30)  NOT null
  , status varchar(30) not null
   , UNIQUE ( cid, stage)
);


INSERT INTO stages (id, cid, stage, status) VALUES
  (1, '1', 'first stage', 'accepted'),
  (2, '1', 'second stage', 'current'),
  (3, '2', 'first stage', 'accepted'),
  (4, '3', 'first stage', 'accepted'),
  (5, '3', 'second stage', 'accepted'),
  (6, '3', 'third stage', 'current')
  ;
ANALYZE stages;

        -- You can fetch all (three) stages with one query
        -- Luckily, {'first', 'second', 'third'} are ordered alphabetically ;-)
        -- --------------------------------------------------------------
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM stages q
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM stages x
        WHERE x.cid = q.cid AND x.stage > q.stage
        );

        -- Some people dont like EXISTS, or think that it is slow.
        -- --------------------------------------------------------------
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT q.*
FROM stages q
JOIN (
        SELECT id
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY cid ORDER BY stage DESC) AS rn
         FROM stages x
        )x ON x.id = q.id AND x.rn = 1;
```

Comment: hmm, I am trying to understand the execution plans here - The exists query actually performed better in this case.